# How do you get an "FWC 1+2 FAULT" warning, if at all, on the Airbus A320?

Tags: airbus-a320, ecam, fwc

ECAM messages are generated through DMC, which is from FWC and SDAC. The FWCs are responsible for ECAM warnings while the SDACs are for ECAM SD and ENG params. (DSC-31-05-30)

My question is: How would you know you have a dual FWC failure if there is no FWC to provide you with warnings anymore? There *IS* a warning `FWS FWC 1+2 FAULT` in FCOM which is not inhibited in any of the flight phases. Is this a warning that will never be triggered?

Additional: I'm aware that ECAM Memo can be used as a source of confirmation since Memo also fails when both FWCs fail. But I'm looking for a more "official" source to confirm if I have no FWCs.

Glossary:

- **DMC** Display Management Computer
- **ECAM** Electronic Centralized Aircraft Monitor

  - **SD** System Display
- **FWC** Flight Warning Computer
- **FWS** Flight Warning System
- **SDAC** System Data Acquisition Concentrator

Comment: That's almost enough TLAs for the Army!

Comment: For those who don't speak Airbus, could somebody decode the acronyms, please?

Comment: @RalphJ I added a glossary.

Comment: @Bianfable Thanks. Is it possible to upvote an edit?  ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

2 FWCs communicate with 3 DMCs to display the messages, as you wrote.

If this link is severed for whatever reason, the DMCs will have missing/faulty inputs and they themselves will display that fault warning. That's why the actions are:

> MONITOR SYS
> MONITOR OVERHEAD PANEL

I.e. you're on your own figuring out the status of the systems.

From the Airbus A320 ATA 31 Technical Training manual:

> If the DMCs receive **no valid data** from both FWCs, the message FWS FWC1 + 2 FAULT is displayed on the EWD. All other EWD messages, aural warnings and attention getters are lost. [emphasis mine]
>
> [image]

Comment: Thank you for the source. Unfortunately as a pilot, we are unable to get our hands on Technical Training Manuals. Is this manual used for training aircraft engineers?

Comment: @YihaoWan: You're very welcome. It is for maintenance training yes. You as a pilot can always follow your company's internal communication channels to ask questions for things that are not clear to you in the FCOM. I added an image.

Comment: That makes it crystal clear, thanks a million.